# Perl - Replace pattern only in lines matching another pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I'm doing an in-place search & replace with Perl. I need to replace all words in all lines that contain another word. For instance, remove all `const` only in lines containing `PMPI_`. With `sed` I can do:

```
sed -i "/PMPI_/ s/const//g" file.c
```

However I need multi-line capabilities and sed doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job. I'm using Perl for everything else anyway. I tried

```
perl -pi -e "/PMPI_/ s/const//g" file.c
```

And other variations with no success. I could only find vim regex equivalents searching this site.

Comment: sed works on multiline.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes but judging by [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290/34931) it seems Perl would be a better candidate for the job.

Comment: @Alex: As far as I can tell, `perl -pi -e "s/const//g if /PMPI_/" file.c` or `perl -pi -e "/PMPI_/ and  s/const//g" file.c` will do what you need. I don't understand your reference to multi-line working though: `PMPI_` can occur in only *one* line at a time!

Comment: @Borodin Yes of course, it was just an example, I didn't post the multi line pattern I'm using.

Comment: @Alex: So for *this* problem you don't need multi-line, but you're looking for a tool that *does* support it? I think you should clarify that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
perl -pi -e "s/const//g if /PMPI_/" file
```

You can also use a logical AND as in many languages derived from C:

```
perl -pi -e "/PMPI_/ && s/const//g" file
```

The second part of the condition `s/const//g` is evaluated only if the first part `/PMPI_/` is true. But even if it is possible to do that, it is a shame in this case to do without the syntax close to natural language that Perl offers.

Note: you say you need multiline capabilities. I don't think you are looking for the slurp mode (that loads the whole file), but you could also work by paragraphs with the `-00` option:

```
echo 'PMPI_ const
const const' | perl -00 -p -e "s/const//g if /PMPI_/"
```